# Packaging on Service fabric Application

Tags: wcf-data-services, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I,m trying to deploy Service Fabric application and package it in order to publish it on a server. I Right-Clicked on project in solution Explorer and clicked on Package but there is nothing in ...\pkg\Release but a ApplicationManifest.xml File.
And also I get the Error The PowerShell script failed to execute:

> Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage

on Release or Publish deploy mode.

Comment: What's the full error log.

Comment: Is your application project referencing any service projects?  Can you F5 your application?

Comment: The PowerShell script failed to execute. See the Output window for Details.   +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                +CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage], FabricImageBuilderValidati 
                 onException
                  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestApplicationPackageErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.TestApplicationPackage

Comment: I can Run the service But not publish it on cluster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have services referenced in your application:

[image]

Or your service projects failed to build. Go through your build output and see if anything failed.